# How to loop through list of nested dictionaries and bring k:v pairs to 1st-level dictionary? JSON data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am working with a JSON list of nested dictionaries, and trying to pull out strings from 2nd level nested dictionaries and make them 1st level k:v pairs. Example original data:

```
data = [{"account #":"54566549", "balance":{"dollars":"684", "euros":"654"}}
        {"account #":"13251462", "balance":{"dollars":"123", "euros":"111"}}
        {"account #":"99871111", "balance":{"dollars":"155", "euros":"422"}}]
```

What I'm trying to do is pull the nested 'balance' dictionaries out so that there is simply a list of dictionaries with three k:v pairs for account #, dollars, and euros, like this:

```
[{"account #":"54566549", "dollars":"684", "euros":"654"}
 {"account #":"13251462", "dollars":"123", "euros":"111"}
 {"account #":"99871111", "dollars":"155", "euros":"422"}]
```

This works one at a time like this:

```
data[0]['dollars'] = data[0]['balance']['dollars']
```

But doing this in a loop yields the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict":

```
for k in data:
    data[k]['dollars'] = data[k]['balance']['dollars']
```

It seems like the issue is I'm referencing the dict ('balance') in the loop which is not permissible, but how else can I reference that string value for nested key 'dollars' and write it to a new key 'dollars' that is part of the 1st-level dictionary?

Also after that is done for dollars + euros, can the original 'balance' dictionaries be safely removed as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through `data` and update each dict with the sub-dict in the `balance` key after popping the key:

```
for d in data:
    d.update(d.pop('balance'))
```

`data` becomes:

```
[{'account #': '54566549', 'dollars': '684', 'euros': '654'},
 {'account #': '13251462', 'dollars': '123', 'euros': '111'},
 {'account #': '99871111', 'dollars': '155', 'euros': '422'}]
```